# Spectrogram and Features size don't match, why?

Tags: python, pyaudio, librosa

Fix the length of the spectrogram to 2000:

`spectrogram = librosa.util.fix_length(spectrogram, size=2000, axis=1)`

Reshape the spectrogram to match the expected shape for the model:

`spectrogram = spectrogram.reshape(1, -1)`

When I comment out the second part, the song detected is always the same

```
import os
import librosa
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pyaudio
 
#Path to the directory containing the sound files and their fingerprints
dataset_directory = "S:\Dawlance\laudio_fingerprints"
 
#Load the dataset with sound fingerprints and labels
dataset = {}
for file in os.listdir(dataset_directory):
 if file.endswith(".npy"):
  fingerprint = np.load(os.path.join(dataset_directory, file))
  label = file.split(".")[0]
  dataset[label] = fingerprint
 print(label, f", starts here ->", fingerprint)
 
 #Prepare the features and labels from the dataset
 features = []
 labels = []
 for label, fingerprint in dataset.items():
  features.append(fingerprint)
  labels.append(label)
 
 #Convert the lists to NumPy arrays
 features = np.array(features)
 labels = np.array(labels)
 print(f"fingerprint shape", fingerprint.shape)
 
 #Reshape features to 2-dimensional
 features = features.reshape(features.shape[0], -1)
 print(f"feature shape", features.shape)
 
 #Train the machine learning model
 model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
 model.fit(features, labels)
 
 #Initialize audio input
 sample_rate = 44100  # Adjust according to your requirements
 chunk_size = 1024  # Number of audio frames per chunk
 hop_size = 512  # Number of audio frames to skip between consecutive chunks
 
 audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
 stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=1, rate=sample_rate, input=True, frames_per_buffer=chunk_size)
 
 #Real-time sound recognition
 print("Listening...")
 
 #Initialize variables for sliding window
 frames = []
 recognition_buffer = []
 window_length = features.shape[1] // hop_size  # Number of chunks needed to match the model's feature length
 
 while True:
  try:
   #Read audio chunk from the stream
   data = stream.read(chunk_size)
   audio_array = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.float32)
 
   #Append audio chunk to the frames buffer
   frames.append(audio_array)
 
   #Process the frames buffer when it contains enough audio for a window
   if len(frames) == window_length:
    #Combine the frames into a single array
    audio_array = np.concatenate(frames)
 
    #Extract spectrogram from the audio using librosa
    spectrogram = np.abs(librosa.stft(audio_array))
 
    #Fix the length of the spectrogram to 2000
    spectrogram = librosa.util.fix_length(spectrogram, size=2000, axis=1)
 
    #Reshape the spectrogram to match the expected shape for the model
    spectrogram = spectrogram.reshape(1, -1)
    print(f"spectrogram shape", spectrogram.shape[1], f"features shape", features.shape[1])
 
    #Ensure the number of features matches the trained model
    if spectrogram.shape[1] != features.shape[1]:
     print("Invalid number of features in the input. Skipping recognition.")
     frames.pop(0)  # Remove the oldest frame to maintain the sliding window
     continue
 
    #Predict the sound label using the trained model
    predicted_label = model.predict(spectrogram)[0]
 
    #Append the recognition result to the buffer
    recognition_buffer.append(predicted_label)
 
    #Print the recognition result if the buffer is full
    if len(recognition_buffer) == window_length:
     #Check if all labels in the buffer are the same
     if all(label == recognition_buffer[0] for label in recognition_buffer):
      print("Recognized sound:", recognition_buffer[0])
      break
     else:
      print("Multiple sounds detected.")
 
    recognition_buffer = []  # Reset the buffer
 
    frames.pop(0)  # Remove the oldest frame to maintain the sliding window
 
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
   #Stop and close the audio stream
   stream.stop_stream()
   stream.close()
   audio.terminate()
   break
```

Comment: The Python content was unreadable due to formatting. Could you check, if indentation is  still correct?

Comment: This post needs a complete reformatting. The code and question is not readable